# ERROR 1064: SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

i want to create a procedure in MySQL/MariaDB, but I get a syntax error which I do not understand.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop$$;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE j INT;
    DECLARE n INT;
    DECLARE c VARCHAR(3);
    SET i = 1;
    SET j = 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM AnswerSets;
    WHILE i < n DO
        WHILE j < 89 DO
            SELECT CONCAT("Q", j) INTO c;
            INSERT INTO T_ANSWER_SET (U_ID, Q_ID, ANSWER) SELECT i, j, c FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = i;
            SET j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

My error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 16: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE j INT;
    DECLARE n ' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Remove the `;` after `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop$$`

Comment: Try removing the semicolon from `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop$$;`.

Comment: getting `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
DELIMITER' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_loop`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE j INT;
    DECLARE n INT;
    DECLARE c VARCHAR(3);
    SET i = 1;
    SET j = 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM AnswerSets;
    WHILE i < n DO
        WHILE j < 89 DO
            SELECT CONCAT("Q", j) INTO c;
            INSERT INTO T_ANSWER_SET (U_ID, Q_ID, ANSWER) SELECT i, j, c FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = i;
            SET j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Should that not work, as a means of debugging try removing all of the proc content in favor of something trivial like `select 1;` and see if the error persists. I've seen this error reported incorrectly before due to a slight syntax error in the proc body.

> To debug the insert, temporarily comment out the `insert into t_answer_set`:

```
...
SELECT CONCAT("Q", j) INTO c;
-- INSERT INTO T_ANSWER_SET (U_ID, Q_ID, ANSWER) 
SELECT i, j, c FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = i;
...
```

Comment: that does is ok as far as syntax is concerned but somehow did it not fill the T_ANSWER_SET table

Comment: Perfect! One problem down! I would comment out the insert statement. See answer.